# Flex Builder dateFormatter timezone offset

Tags: android, timezone, flash-builder, flexbuilder

I Have a Flex Mobile app that gets a rss feed and the timezone is incorrect. I would like it to be in CST Central Time. Need to format the timezone. I have pasted working code below but need to fix the timezone issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        xmlns:ns1="*"
        backgroundColor="#74171E" title="Mediacom 2 / Paulbunyan 32"
        viewActivate="refresh()">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function getData():void
            {
                getDataResult.token = iCTVChannel232.getData();
            }
            public function refresh(): void {
                getData();
            }
            private function dateFormat(item:Object,column:GridColumn):String
            {
                return pubDateFormatter.format(item.pubDate);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:DateTimeFormatter id="pubDateFormatter" useUTC="false" dateTimePattern="MM-dd K:mm a"/>
        <s:CallResponder id="getDataResult"/>
        <ns1:ICTVChannel232 id="iCTVChannel232"/> 
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:DataGrid id="dataGrid" left="10" right="10" top="10" bottom="10">
        <s:columns>
            <s:ArrayList>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="pubDate" width="80" headerText="Date" labelFunction="dateFormat"></s:GridColumn>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="title" headerText="title"></s:GridColumn>
            </s:ArrayList>
        </s:columns>
        <s:AsyncListView list="{getDataResult.lastResult}"/>

    </s:DataGrid>
    <s:actionContent>
        <s:Button icon="@Embed('/assets/refreshico.png')"
                  click="Object(navigator.activeView).refresh()"/>
    </s:actionContent>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Date object in Flash is always set to the computer's time settings. If the computer is already in the CDT timezone, then just getting any property from the object will be good. However, if you want to do a timezone 'conversion' into a timezone that the computer is not set to, you can get the UTC time and offset it like this for CDT:

```
var date:Date = new Date();
var timezone:int = -5;
date.hours = date.hoursUTC + timezone;
```

However, you're trying to get the actual CDT time, which only works during the summer in certain areas. For this, it's impossible for Flash to know exactly when that is UNLESS you code the exceptions (ie. if between this date and that date, do -6, else do -5) and you also need to know the actual location of the user (which is impossible through Flash unless the user gives you that info).

```
<fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function getData():void
            {
                getDataResult.token = iCTVChannel232.getData();
            }
            public function refresh(): void {
                getData();
            }
            private function dateFormat(item:Object,column:GridColumn):String
            {
                var date:Date = item.pubDate;
                var timezone:int = -5;
                date.hours = date.hoursUTC + timezone;
                return pubDateFormatter.format(date);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
```

Comment: The app is target for a small area. We are a public access Television station in Minnesota and the app is intended for our viewing area.

Comment: I am New to flex could you help me with placement of the code in the example above. I have tried to place

Comment: After runing the edited code it returns errors below. I do appreciate All your help in helping me figure this out.

Comment: TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "Thu, 02 Feb 2012 15:00:00 GMT" to Date.
 at views::Channel2Schedule/dateFormat()